# `env.is_feature_activated` error when set contract

Tags: smart-contract

I'm trying to set up my eos enviroment. When I post the system contracts I get this error msg:

```
Error 3070000: WASM Exception
Error Details: env.is_feature_activated unresolveable
```

enviroment: ubuntu 18
eos: v1.8.1
cdt: v1.8.1
sys contracts: 1.7.0

can someone advise?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still post system contract but first activate that protocol feature for v1.8.x node:

TLDR:

1. add `eosio::producer_api_plugin`
2. run `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/producer/schedule_protocol_feature_activations -d '{"protocol_features_to_activate": ["0ec7e080177b2c02b278d5088611686b49d739925a92d9bfcacd7fc6b74053bd"]}'`

If it doesn't work:

1. run `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/producer/get_supported_protocol_features`
2. find `feature_digest` value for `PREACTIVATE_FEATURE`
3. use it in above's curl.

Reference: https://www.jianshu.com/p/99bdf3f908f6

Answer (score 5):

`is_feature_activated` is new intrinsic which is introduced in EOSIO v1.8.x. It would be activated by hard fork, but not yet supported. Use `release/1.6.x` branch now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm told this will let you continue with the newest versions: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/7180

Comment: For editors: I'd like to keep the github issue url and not copy in the instructions. The github issue instructions will potentially change, making anything copied here become out of date.